# wget for windows 7? trusted source

Tags: wget, windows-7-x64

I am looking for wget for windows 7, 64 bit.

GNU wget has a package for for windows 32 bits, and it can be downloaded from sourceforge. But my computer does not meet the system requirements: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html

Could you suggest a trusted source to download it from?

Comment: I think I use this binary at work.

Comment: @rekire I don't understand. Are you referring to the file I point to in my post?

Comment: Yes, I'll need to check it, but I think I use the linked binaries.

Comment: related to http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this version here?
http://www.alexlomas.com/blog/2005/08/64_bit_wget_for_windows/

> Be warned however, this doesn’t contain the SSL libraries so will not
>   work against https sites.

Comment: I saw it before I posted this question, but I don't know if I can trust the source. Have you used this download yourself? Thank you

Comment: No, i'm running a 32-bit. But you could do an online scan and see if its clean: http://onlinescan.avast.com/

Comment: Thank you, it appears to be fine. Once in operation, if there are any problems I will post here.

Answer (score 6):

You can download **Wget** from **Cygwin 64 bit** package installer.

http://cygwin.com/install.html

Answer (score 2):

You can get version 1.16 (as of today) 32 and 64 bit binaries from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/